# text to voice software

Tags: text-to-speech

Which programming language is suitable to create an application software like text to voice converter.

Comment: You really should be thinking about available DSP libraries and then choose the language to develop your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's .NET framework has the `System.Speech.Synthesis` library which will accommodate your needs.

(Although dirkgently's comment is more generally still valid)